# Why can't I change link_to text color without using !important in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to change my `link_to` text color. I've seen numerous questions and articles where people can change the `link_to` text color without the `!important` property. But my links' colors won't change without it. Was this because of a recent change, or am I doing something wrong?
I did notice that when I refresh the page, for a split second, the links are changed to the colors I've assigned to them, but then immediately changes back to the default gray color.

#### Recreating the issue

Run `rails new app`.

Run `cd app`

Run `rails g scaffold Car model:string`.

Add the following code to the `app/assets/stylesheets/applications.css` file.

```
.test {
  color: red;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

Add a link to the `app/views/layouts/applications.html.erb` file (within the body tag).

```
<%= link_to 'Testing', nil, class: "test" %>
```

#### Result

[image: showcase]

`Testing` is the link's color I'm trying to change. As mentioned, the text color of the link doesn't change, however, the padding is successfully applied.

While inspecting, I also noticed that the color property is lined out.

[image: inspection of HTML]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using scaffold, it's important to be aware of what scaffold creates. For me personally, scaffold is nice for quick basic crud stuff. However it comes with a lot.

As for your issue scaffold creates a scaffold.scss which overwrites your styling. Try commenting it out and then it should work(It did for me!).

Comment: Thank you! That was the issue. I've been struggling for days trying to figure it out. I really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 2):

Fastest way to find out where this one is coming from is to click on the funnel icon, next to `red;`. It will filter you every place that color is applied to the element. There should probably be some `!important` declared below your CSS but it's still takes the upper hand.

When it's stroked, it's saying that it's overwritten elsewhere, it's a wrong CSS property or alike.

Comment: You're entirely correct. I commented out an `a:active` pseudo class, and my colors were successfully applied. The main issue came from the `scaffold.scss`. It was overriding my styles.

Answer (score 2):

This issue has nothing to do with Rails or link_to. You are simply trying to style your `a.test` element.

You definitely do not need to use `important` ESPECIALLY for a new app. The CSS cascade can get complex, but this shouldn't be a complex situation.

CSS is based on both a cascade and specificity. You probably have other CSS (above the part you pasted in the inspector) that is overwriting the `.test` class, or something in the CSS is being more specific (since you're only styling `.test`.

Since this is a link (a) you should try to do `a.test` in your CSS, and you may also need to also style `:hover` and `:visited` pseudo classes.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I only just noticed (thanks to AceCleric) that the styles I wrote were being overwritten by the `scaffold.scss` file. And you're right. When I was more specific with my selectors, everything did work.